# Gmail is clipping html email for no reason

Tags: node.js, email, gmail, sendgrid

We use node.js to format html email sent by SendGrid to users to confirm account creation or other things like that. The email is sent correctly. All the content is displayed correctly. But, in Gmail, even if all the content is displayed correctly, there is a message at the end saying that the email was truncated and to click the link to to display all. If we click, we got the same content with some missing style. The same email in an other language will not display this message. But all email have the same structure. The email is lower than 30KB (code + images)

You will find the expended code above. (content have been changed)
Following by the content generated in a ejs file.

I read the code many time to find any issue (missing tags).
I tried to send it manually and the notification didn't appear.
I calculated the weight to be sure it's over 102KB. Result: 30KB max.
I compared code with an other one that don't have this issue. Nothing different on the structure. Only content differ.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta 
        http-equiv="Content-Type" 
        content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style>
            body{
                font-family:Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif;
                font-size:14px;
                color:#000;
                margin:0
            }
            a{
                text-decoration:none
            }
            a.link{
                color:#EB3052;
                font-weight:700
            }
            a.button{
                background-color:#EB3052;
                color:#fff;
                padding:10px;
                border-radius:5px;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                font-size:12px;
                font-weight:700;
                letter-spacing:1px
            }
            a.button.decline{
                background-color:#f5f7f7;
                color:#EB3052;
                font-weight:400
            }
            ul{
                line-height:24px
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div 
        style="
            width:100%; 
            height: 100%; 
            text-align:center; 
            font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; 
            background-color: #F5F7F6;
        " 
        align="center"
        >
            <table 
            width="600px" 
            cellspacing="0" 
            cellpadding="0" 
            border="0" 
            align="center" 
            style="
                padding: 14px;
            "
            >
                <tr>
                    <td 
                    height="32" 
                    width="30" 
                    style="padding: 14px;"
                    >
                        <a 
                        href="url"
                        >
                            <img 
                            src="url" 
                            border="0" 
                            alt="url" 
                            style="
                                max-height: 60px
                            " 
                            />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table 
                        width="100%" 
                        style="
                            background: #fff; 
                            text-align: left; 
                            font-size:16px; 
                            padding-top: 40px; 
                            padding-bottom: 40px;
                        "
                        >
                            <tr>
                                <td 
                                style="
                                    padding-left: 32px; 
                                    padding-right: 32px;
                                "
                                >
                                    <table 
                                    width="100%" 
                                    cellspacing="0" 
                                    cellpadding="0" 
                                    border="0"
                                    >
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div 
                                                style="
                                                    width:100%; 
                                                    height: 100%; 
                                                    text-align:left; 
                                                    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; 
                                                    line-height:18px;
                                                "
                                                >
                                                    Hi 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Thanks to your contribution of $<%- body.amount %> to <%- body.recipient %>, the fundraising goal is one step closer!
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Here is your transaction information:
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <strong>
                                                        Transaction information
                                                    </strong>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Transaction number: 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Recipient: 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Amount: 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Type: 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Date: 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Payment method: 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <strong>
                                                        Billing information
                                                    </strong>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Full name: 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Email address: 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Postal code: 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Country: 
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Thank you for your generosity!
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Sincerely,
                                                    <br/>
                                                    <br/>
                                                    Lorem
                                                    <br>
                                                    <br>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td 
                    style="
                        background: url(url), #EB3052; 
                        background-repeat-x: repeat; 
                        background-position-x: center; 
                        height: 8px;
                    "
                    >   
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr 
                style="
                    background-color:#EB3052; 
                    text-align: left;
                "
                >
                    <td 
                    style="
                        padding-top:14px; 
                        padding-bottom:14px; 
                        padding-left: 32px; 
                        padding-right: 32px; 
                        color:#fff; 
                        font-size: 12px;
                    "
                    >
                        <strong>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        </strong>
                        <br/>
                        <strong>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        </strong>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td 
                    style="
                        text-align:center; 
                        height:24px; 
                        font-size: 13px; 
                        color:#B1B1B1; 
                        padding-top:14px; 
                        padding-bottom:14px; 
                        padding-left: 32px; 
                        padding-right: 32px;
                    "
                    >
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        <span 
                        style="
                            color:#FFFFFF;
                        "
                        >
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        </span>
                         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <a 
                        href="url" 
                        style="
                            color: #B1B1B1;
                        "
                        >
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        </a>
                         | 
                        <a 
                        href="url" 
                        style="
                            color: #B1B1B1;
                        "
                        >
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        </a>
                         | 
                        <a 
                        href="url" 
                        style="
                            color: #B1B1B1;
                        ">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                        </a>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <a 
                        href="url"
                        >
                            <img 
                            src="url" 
                            border="0" 
                            alt="url" 
                            style="
                                max-height: 64px
                            "
                            />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
Hi <%- body.firstName %>!<br/><br/>
Thanks to your contribution of $<%- body.amount %> to <%- body.recipient %>, the fundraising goal is one step closer!<br/><br/>
Here is your transaction information:<br/><br/>
<strong>Transaction information</strong><br/>
Transaction number: <%- body.transactionNumber %><br/>
Recipient: <%- body.recipient %><br/>
Amount: $<%- body.amount %> <%- body.currency %><br/>
Type: <%- body.type %><br/>
Date: <%- body.date %><br/>
Payment method: <%- body.payment %><br/><br/>
<strong>Billing information</strong><br/>
<% if (body.organizationName) { %>
Company name: <%- body.organizationName %><br/>
<% } %>
Full name: <%- body.firstName %> <%- body.lastName %><br/>
Email address: <%- body.email %><br/>
Postal code: <%- body.postalCode %><br/>
Country: <%- body.country %><br/><br/>
Thank you for your generosity!<br/><br/>
Sincerely,<br/><br/>
<%- sender.name %>
```

The email is correctly is correctly and completely displayed, but a notification is displayed at the end of the email saying it was truncated (but not).

The notification should not appear in this case.

How to prevent Gmail to display the notification at the end of the email when the email is already correctly and completely displayed?

Answer (score 6):

In my case the issue was caused by one non-ASCII character in the email (specifically `ä`) - adding it to any part of the message clips it in gmail.

I'm certain that I'm encoding the email in utf-8, perhaps sendgrid reincodes it somehow later on.

Comment: +1 to what @Ridim said. We also discovered that if you replace the character with the appropriate HTML entity (e.g. &eacute; _or_ &#235;) then Gmail is happy. 

For .Net devs, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode will do the trick.

Comment: If it can help someone - I just stumbled across 'the clipping issue' as well adding nordic chars (æ,ø,å) in varables which were stuffed into a dynamic template using {{ someVariable }}. By combining HttpUtility.HtmlEncode as mentioned by @Jedidja and using {{{ someVariable }}} in the dynamic template, the clipping issue disappeared - and the characters (æ,ø,å) are displayed correctly as well.

Comment: Just wanted to mention: I used the © character in the footer, and that caused the issue for me

Comment: I'm using SendGrid's visual designer and in a Text Module I had &copy; but SendGrid was converting the HTML entity to the © character which was causing the issue. I had to convert the Text Module into a Code Module so that SendGrid wouldn't convert it.

Comment: Also had the same issue because of the copyright character. Changed it to HTML entity and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Mine had `&nbsp;` and that was enough to cause it, using Sendgrid.  As soon as I cleaned those out, the issue went away.  Now to magically prevent those from appearing in new emails....

Comment: Me again: After everything was okay, it started clipping again. Then I realised I changed the company name to my full Estonian company name Proxytool OÜ. And the Ü caused it again...

Comment: This solved my problem as well. The © in the email was causing the ENTIRE email to get clipped.